# Jmeter stop the current iteration issue

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

how to stop current iteration using jmeter and move to next iteration using beanshell script.
(Without using test action element)

I tried ctx.setRestartNextLoop(true) but this is not working.

JMeter version: 5.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting
2. If for some reason (I fail to see any valid reason though) you still want to do this using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) instead of [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler - the relevant code would be:

   ```
   SampleResult.setIgnore()
   ctx.setTestLogicalAction(org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction.START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_CURRENT_LOOP)
   ```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Can you give me the code snippet for groovy lang for this usecase, so that i can try the same? And i tried the beanshell assertion with following code and its not working.

import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction;
import java.io.*;
String s1= ${SampleValue};
if(s1.contains("Hello"))
{
SampleResult.setIgnore();
ctx.setTestLogicalAction(org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction.START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_CURRENT_LOOP);
}

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Did I mention "Beanshell Assertion" anywhere? I clearly stated **JSR223 Sampler**, you [should not be using Beanshell for anything since JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead)